# In Android, is there a way to get notified when a contact's photo changes (via receiver, listener, etc)?

Tags: android, photo, contacts, photos

My app uses a custom layout do display all the contact info, including photos. It's designed to handle a very large amount of contacts (in the 1000s), and I've created a cache for the contact photos to make them load much faster. However, I'm running into issues when contact photos are updated on the phone. Since I'm using cached ones, the new photo doesn't show up in the app until it's force-closed and then restarted. And I don't want to use anything like a last-accessed timestamp to refresh the cached photos because doing so would significantly slow down the app every time a refresh is needed.

So, ideally, I would like to get notified (via something like a broadcast receiver) whenever a contact photo is changed, and I can then update that photo in the cache. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

user [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) instead to update your gui automatically. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/525313/Using-Cursor-Loader-in-Android) you can see a tutorial. Obviously there are plenty of other examples out there.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with loading the photos quicker. I'm already doing all the updates on a backgroud thread, and I already implemented a photo cache to make is much faster. The issue is detecting photo changes and updating the cache when they happen.

Comment: Using CursorLoader is recommended because it updates asynchronously and automatically whenever the data source changes. In this case the ContactsProvider.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ContentObserver.

```
public class ContractObserv extends Activity {

MyContentObserver observer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    observer=new MyContentObserver();
    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, observer);

}


  private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public MyContentObserver() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            Log.d("Androider", "INSIDE ONcHANGE");
        }

    }}
```

Its amazing that once you run it and every time a contact changes, the OnChange is called until you unregister it.

Comment: This will get triggered every time there is any change to a contact, which is excessive. I would like to only be notified when the photo gets changed.

Comment: In this ContentObserver; Is there a way to get details of contact which added or changed ?? I want to create a similar listener but want to perform some operation on added/modified contact.

Comment: This is not very useful because it will only be called while your app is running which it probably isn't when the contact is changed.